# How does TensorFlow sync tensors which share a buffer between different step-ids

Tags: tensorflow

I have a problem in my contrib implementation for distributed TensorFlow. Not to bother you with non-relevant details, the solution applies a certain message protocol in order to utilize RDMA writes directly from/to source/destination tensors, to save memory copies on the CPU.

Let's say I have 2 sides, `A` and `B`, and `A` wants to receive a tensor from `B`.
The protocol is as follows:

- `A` sends a `REQUEST` message to `B`.
- `B` lookups the tensor locally (`BaseRendezvousMgr::RecvLocalAsync`) and sends a `META-DATA` response to `A`.
- `A` uses the meta data to allocate the destination tensor, and sends a `ACK` to `B` containing the destination address.
- `B` receives the `ACK`, and performs a remote DMA write to the destination address.

Between the `REQUEST` and the `ACK`, `B` keeps the local tensor alive (and Ref() > 0), by saving it in a local map (the `REQUEST` copies the tensor to the local map, the `ACK` pops it from the map).

To validate my solution, I added a checksum calculation at each step. Occasionally, I see that the checksum changes between the `REQUEST` and the `ACK`. This happens when I run PS with two workers:

[image]

- **Line 1** is `REQUEST` to worker 0.
- **Line 2** is `ACK` to worker 0.
- **Line 3** is `REQUEST` to worker 1.
- **Line 4** is `ACK` to worker 1.

The last value on each line is the checksum. The errors happens about 50% of the times. I always see it on line 4.

I also saw that the problematic tensor has a shared buffer for all step-ids **(this is a given. I can't control it)**. So it is very likely that some other thread changed the tensor's content between lines 3 and 4, which is something I want to prevent.

So the question is how? What prevented the content from changing between lines 1 and 2, and 2 and 3? To emphasize, the time elapsed between lines 3 and 4 is less than **0.04 seconds**, while the time elapsed between 2 and 3 is almost **2.5 seconds**.

Thanks for your help. Code will be posted if required.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using tf.Variable for the shared buffer? If so using tfe.Variable (to enable reasonable read-write semantics) or tf.get_variable(..., use_resource=True) to construct it will make any synchronization issues go away.

Otherwise this is hard to understand without knowing more about the generating graph.